# Why can we not use combinations?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

. A 3-person basketball team consists of a guard, a forward, and a centre.
a) If a person is chosen at random from each of three different such teams, what is the probability of selecting a
complete team?

the answer to this question is
$\frac{3\times 2\times 1}{3\times 3\times 3}$

I am not understanding why can't it be $\frac{3\times 2\times 1}{{}^9C_3}$

Comment: You aren't choosing $3$ people from the total $9$.  You can't, say, just choose all three members of team $A$.  Rather you are choosing one member from each team...that's $3^3$ choices.

Comment: Note:  If you want the exercise, you could look at a variant problem here.  Suppose we are choosing $3$ people  without replacement from the entire $9$ (so your denominator of $\binom 93$ would be correct). Now ask the same question.  What's the probability of selecting one guard, one forward, and one center now?

Answer (score 1):

Let those three types of players be labeled as A,B,C 
Now you have 6 different ways to select them such as ABC,ACB,BCA,BAC,CAB,CBA and actually these are different permutations and not combinations.
Probability of selecting one player from a team is 1/3  
Since selecting from three teams are independent, probability of selecting three players without considering the permutations is
(1/3)×(1/3)×(1/3) and the final answer is that multiplied by 6. Therefore the answer is 2/9.